# Batch variable echoing not working on Atari Portfolio

Tags: batch-file, dos

I just found an old Atari Portfolio and i'm trying to write some simple batch scripts on it. However, if I try to echo a variable it doesn't work.
I already tried almost everything for setting and echoing:

```
:: Setting variable
SET var=1
SET "var=1"
SET var = 1

:: Echoing
echo %var%
echo %%var
echo !%var%!
```

Nothing worked. Also `set /p "var=Enter here >"` is not working.

The OS is Dip-DOS 2.11 and I found no site that explains whats the difference to "regular" DOS.

Answer (score 1):

DIP-Dos is compatible with MS-Dos 2.11, that means you are quite limited when it comes to commands.

I am quite sure that set /p is way too new for this OS. Does set work on the command line ?

[image]

Comment: Yes, thanks, thats the way it behaves. But I didn't find a way to echo the value in MS-DOS 2.11 either. Is there any?

Comment: @GuntherRocket I don't think so, perhaps set | find "A=" is the solution that comes nearest. I feel like searching masm and compiling something ;-)

Comment: Too sad there is no `find` command ;-) Edit: There somehow has to be a way, i can't even do a simple if statement because `if %var%==1` doesn't work.

Comment: What a shame the Atari contains a cut down version, a normal dos 2.11 contains find ftp://ftp.oldskool.org/pub/tvdog/tandy1000/documents/3k4101.zip